# Wordpress plugin returning site name

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, widget

http://codex.wordpress.org/WPMU_Functions/get_current_site#Examples

In Wordpress, I am trying to retrieve the site name inside a plugin using the above function:

```
echo 'You are viewing '.get_current_site()->site_name;
echo '<br/>Domain '.get_current_site()->domain;
echo '<br/>id  '.get_current_site()->id ;
echo '<br/>path '.get_current_site()->path;
```

Unfortunately this is returning info from the top level site, not whichever subsite the plugin is on, which I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i would think you can do it with:

get_bloginfo('name');

Comment: Note: I did a strtolower on this to pass this into the url I was building.